# Python Discord Bot Embed Userinformation

Tags: python

i am currently programming a discord bot with Python and i want him to show an embed with all the user informations ( Name, since when he is using discord, since when he is on the server).
My problem is that he is only working when you use his name (!userinfo "Bot") but not when you use an actual user. Please help me.

```
if message.content.startswith('!userinfo'):
        args = message.content.split(' ')
        if len(args) == 2:
            member: Member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: args[1] in client.user.name, message.guild.members)
            if member:
                embed = discord.Embed(title='Userinfo for {}'.format(member.name),
                                      description='This if the Userinfo from  {}'.format(member.mention),
                                      color=0x22a7f0)
                embed.add_field(name='Joined server', value=member.joined_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S'),
                                inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name='Joined Discord', value=member.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S'),
                                inline=True)
                rollen = ''
                for role in member.roles:
                    if not role.is_default():
                        rollen += '{} \r\n'.format(role.mention)
                if rollen:
                    embed.add_field(name='Roles', value=rollen, inline=True)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text='I am an`enter code here` EmbedFooter.')
                mess = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish can be done in a much simpler way.

If you just use `discord.ext.commands` you can access information directly from the `context`, instead of doing a lot of string processing:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def userinfo(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    # then you build your embed with the user info extracted from member
```